# Schoenberg correspondence on $L^p$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Schoenberg correspondence states that $\psi: \mathbb R^d\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is conditionally positive definite and hermitian if and only if $e^{t\psi}$ is positive definite for each $t>0$. My question: Is this statement also true if $\psi : L^p \longrightarrow \mathbb C$?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: $\psi$ is positive definite and hermitian on $L^p$ if for all $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n \in L^p$ and $z_1,...,z_n \in \mathbb C$
$$\sum_{i,j} z_i\overline{z_j}\psi(\varphi_i-\varphi_j) \geq 0$$
and 
$$\overline{\psi(\varphi)}=\psi(-\varphi)$$

Comment: What is your definition for conditional positive definiteness of a function on $L^p$?

Comment: Bochner's theorem on infinite dimensional spaces (such as  Banach spaces, or more generally, locally convex spaces) can be tricky. Also, in numerical analysis, there is a condition of conditional positivity that looks a bit different than what you wrote; see e.g. the book *Scattered Data Approximation*, by  H. Wendland.